# Building QtTreePropertyBrowser package with pre-built Qt Creator

Tags: build, widget, qt-creator

I've found a [link](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/source/80592b0e7145fb876ea0e84a6e3dadfd5f7481b6%3aqtpropertybrowser) that I was searching for to have the "QtTreePropertyBrowser" widget on my Qt Creator. Nevertheless, I don't know how to build it. What is the work flow? I'm using Qt Creator that is already built taken from Synaptic Manager, Ubuntu (pre-built). Should I compile from source first the Qt Creator in order to build the package of QtTreePropertyBrowser that I've just found?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried to build and integrate a component into Qt-Designer so the following is just a guess, but I hope I show you the right direction: you do not need to compile Qt-Creator, what you need is to compile the component which is a plugin for Qt Designer. I can recommend two documents:

There is an [INSTALL.TXT](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/source/80592b0e7145fb876ea0e84a6e3dadfd5f7481b6%3aqtpropertybrowser/INSTALL.TXT) in the source code you found which tries to answer some of the questions you asked. These are the headlines:

```
INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS
Unpacking and installation
1.  Unpacking the archive (if you have not done so already).
2.  Configuring the package.
3.  Building the component and examples (when required).
4.  Building the Qt Designer plugin (optional).
Using a component in your project
```

In Qt's doc there is a page called [Creating Custom Widgets for Qt Designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html).